# django rest Framework authentications

Tags: python, django, rest, access-token, django-rest-framework

I have developed an API using django rest framework and have used Token based authentication, Now I have trying to use it from separate project. How I can login using userid and password and get token in response and use token in header in all next url calls.

From Shell I have checked token for one of the user and tested api from terminal and it's working like,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/corporate/company/ -H 'Authorization: Token 9f4702dfddbf89e0346b2ffd10fd69173c178273'
```

But how to use this token in http calls?

I have included rest_framework.authtoken in installed app and included url in urls.py as:

```
url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token')
```

Now I have trying to get it accessed from another project, where I have made one of the login form? Now the Question is where to post form and what fields should be there in form. If I have posted form then token will be returned in response then how Can I parse and use in headers on next calls?

I have gone through tutorial and API guide but no help. On how to access api in my project while Api is ready and login is working through browser-able api url.

Answer (score 3):

Django rest framerwork supports many auth options. You can use Basic Auth if you want.
If you want to use the token you will need to set an http header with the correct token for your user.

From the docs you need to set it as (replace 99... with yours)

```
Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b
```

Comment: This is what I have already mentioned in my Question. My Problem is how to plug it to url from completely independent project, getting data over url.

Comment: into the language of your choice you would need to set the headers on the http call. in python you can do something like - import httplib ... httpheaders = {'Authorization' : 'Token 99...your_token'} and when you call the url you add the header - connection.request('GET', 'index.html', headers=headers)